# How do I set TeamCity to not produce build artifacts when the build fails?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-6

How do I set up TeamCity so that it does not publish build artifacts if the build fails because a unit test failed? I'm pretty sure it worked this way prior to version 6.0, but since upgrading to 6.0 it always produces artifacts even if a test fails. I have "Fail build if at least one test failed" checked.

We had an outage with the e-mail notification and I didn't know we had a build problem because it continued producing artifacts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please watch/vote for this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-12194

Comment: For a workaround, see this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-12194#focus=streamItem-27-2627082-0-0